# Nuget in Visual Studio 2015 ignores allowedVersions?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I have an MVC5 project that uses jQuery, included through Nuget package manager.
I want to keep the project on the 1.x branch.
This is done using the allowedVersions attribute in packages.config:

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" allowedVersions="[1.10.2, 2.0.0)" />
```

Since I switched to VS 2015, this is ignored, Nuget suggests 2.1.4 (at the time of writing) as newer version.
Also tried variations like [1.10.2, 2) and [1.1, 2).
Is this a bug or a newer mechanism is used now to achieve this?

Comment: Well, I'll buy that but what do expect *us* to do about it?  Use the project's [bug tracker](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues) to report this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been reported here on the NuGet project:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1094

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if the behavior has yet changed in VS2015, but in VS2013, the allowedVersions check is only done at the "project" level and not the Solution level.  So if you did Manage Nuget option when you had the solution selected, it will pick up newer versions as available, but if you try and update them, it usually stops you from applying the update to the projects that have the allowedVersion tag set.

If you right clicked a project in Solution Explorer and did Manage Nuget, then it would not show jQuery because of the allowedVersion tag.

It still appears to be an issue in Nuget for VS2015: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/333